# Hide what I type into Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

Some commands require putting in the password as one of the arguments (like `net use`, for example). Is it possible to run a command or change a setting in Command Prompt so that whatever I am typing does not show up on the screen? I basically want to type something without seeing what I'm typing and then press enter and have the command execute (the output can show).

Note that this is NOT for a batch file.

Comment: You can, of course, create a batch file to input a password param without using *echo*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use an asterisk (*) instead of your password in `net use`**

In Microsoft Technet we read:

> **Net use**
>
> ...
>
> **Password**: Specifies the password needed to access the
>   shared resource. Type an asterisk (*) to produce a prompt for the
>   password. The password is not displayed when you type it at the
>   password prompt.

So, just use * (a single asterisk) instead of your password in the command line, and then you will be prompted to type your password and it is not displayed on the screen.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx

---

**Other possible use cases:**

There may be other use cases rather than `net use`, so this is a general answer to the question:

*Please note that you should assume that there is usually no way to completely hide what you are typing from everyone, and these are some tricks to hide it from the curious people who stare at your monitor!*

**Solution 1: Changing color**

One solution is changing the foreground color to black on a black background. You can not do this in command line by issuing the command `color 00` because it returns error when you try to use the same color for both the foreground and the bacground. So, do this using properties of the command prompt window

[image: Command prompt properties]

After typing your command, this command will change back to original using this command:

```
color 07
```

or this

```
color /t
```

Note: You should clear screen before returning back to the original color using

```
cls
```

Comment: It works but you can still get the text by marking or selecting. That would not be useful for hiding a password that Is typed.

Comment: @MC10 What do you mean by hiding? It is not possible to completely hide it. If OP describe your exact purpose, maybe I can help.

Comment: echo off and echo on would just change when the system reports back

Comment: It may be impossible to hide, so that is what we should tell OP. I don't have a purpose and I think OP's purpose is to prevent passwords being typed in to be visible.

Comment: @MC10 I think the use case is clear: Typing passwords in a hidden way. So I think the above commands does the job. Isn't it?

Comment: @MC10 I have added two things: 1) Recipe for `net use` with hidden typing of password 2) A disclaimer as you've said

Comment: echo off and echo on will not hide what you type, as @El Turner noted

Comment: Thanks for the useful information on `net use` though!

Comment: @pkr298 Thanks, I removed it. Have you tested the first one? Did it work proerly? Btw, I am searching for better solutions for general situations.

Comment: The question is to "type something without seeing what I'm typing and then press enter and have the command execute", similar to entering a password in `net use`, which doesn't display what is being typed.